# GetDPLocations failed with error 0x80004005

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, sccm, sccm-2012

My VM SCCM windows 2012 R2 server can't get a sccm-client on my windows 7 VM.

I tried client-push and the CCMSetup.exe is running, but eventually stops.

The ccmsetup.log gives me **GetDPLocations failed with error 0x80004005**:

```
<![LOG[Sending message header '<Msg SchemaVersion="1.1"><ID>{50C62C2C-DD4B-4314-9623-C554140C1312}</ID><SourceHost>DIEDERIKSPC</SourceHost>
<TargetAddress>mp:[http]MP_LocationManager</TargetAddress>
<ReplyTo>direct:DIEDERIKSPC:LS_ReplyLocations</ReplyTo>
<Priority>3</Priority><Timeout>600</Timeout><ReqVersion>5931</ReqVersion>
<TargetHost>WIN-52BO8J9011M.poliforma.nl</TargetHost>
<TargetEndpoint>MP_LocationManager</TargetEndpoint>
<ReplyMode>Sync</ReplyMode><Protocol>http</Protocol><SentTime>2017-10-09T16:48:38Z</SentTime><Body Type="ByteRange" Offset="0" Length="1120"/><Hooks>
<Hook3 Name="zlib-compress"/></Hooks><Payload Type="inline"/></Msg>']LOG]!>
<time="18:48:38.081-120" date="10-09-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="868" file="siteinfo.cpp:177">
<![LOG[CCM_POST 'HTTP://WIN-52BO8J9011M.poliforma.nl/ccm_system/request']LOG]!><time="18:48:38.081-120" date="10-09-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="868" file="httphelper.cpp:807">
<![LOG[Failed to receive ccm message response. Status code = 404]LOG]!><time="18:48:38.096-120" date="10-09-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="2" thread="868" file="httphelper.cpp:1694">
<![LOG[GetDPLocations failed with error 0x80004005]LOG]!>
<time="18:48:38.096-120" date="10-09-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="868" file="siteinfo.cpp:532">
<![LOG[Failed to get DP locations as the expected version from MP 'WIN-52BO8J9011M.poliforma.nl'. Error 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="18:48:38.096-120" date="10-09-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="2" thread="868" file="ccmsetup.cpp:10926">
<![LOG[A Fallback Status Point has not been specified.  Message with STATEID='101' will not be sent.]LOG]!><time="18:48:38.096-120" date="10-09-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="868" file="ccmsetup.cpp:9428">
<![LOG[Next retry in 10 minute(s)...]LOG]!><time="18:48:38.096-120" date="10-09-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="868" file="ccmsetup.cpp:8498">
```

My SCCM site is published to my domain. I have set the domainadmin as the account for client-push installations. I ran Extadsch.exe as admin. I have a system management container with delegated full permission to my sccm server. I have allowed inbound and outbound ports on the firewall with a group policy:

- TCP 80,443,445,10123,135,2701,8530,1433,4022
- UDP 9,25536,67,68,135
- File & Printer Sharing,
- WMI

The remote differential compression feature is installed.

I installed the BITS feature. I also noticed the users weren't found in sccm. I don't know if that was a problem, but I enabled AD user and group discovery.

The ccmsetup.log is different now:

```
<![LOG[Received header '<Msg SchemaVersion="1.1">
<ID>{CC1F4564-DD1E-46D2-9771-E10CE01041EE}</ID>
<SourceID>GUID:49295132-F8E6-4600-9903-51390C758F97</SourceID>
<SourceHost>WIN-52BO8J9011M</SourceHost>
<TargetAddress>direct:DIEDERIKSPC:LS_ReplyLocations</TargetAddress>
<ReplyTo>MP_LocationManager</ReplyTo>
<CorrelationID>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</CorrelationID>
<Priority>3</Priority>
<Timeout>600</Timeout>
<TargetHost>DIEDERIKSPC</TargetHost>
<TargetEndpoint>LS_ReplyLocations</TargetEndpoint><ReplyMode>Sync</ReplyMode><Protocol>http</Protocol><SentTime>2017-10-17T09:39:15Z</SentTime><Body Type="ByteRange" Offset="0" Length="1254"/><Hooks><Hook3 Name="zlib-compress"/><Hook Name="authenticate"><Property Name="Signature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roperty><Property Name="AuthSenderMachine">WIN-52BO8J9011M;WIN-52BO8J9011M.poliforma.nl;</Property><Property Name="MPSiteCode">RSP</Property></Hook></Hooks><Payload Type="inline"/></Msg>']LOG]!><time="11:39:15.941-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="3064" file="httphelper.cpp:1724">
<![LOG[Received reply body '<ContentLocationReply SchemaVersion="1.00"><ContentInfo PackageFlags=""><ContentHashValues/></ContentInfo><Sites><Site><MPSite SiteCode="RSP" MasterSiteCode="RSP" SiteLocality="LOCAL" IISPreferedPort="" IISSSLPreferedPort=""/><LocationRecords/></Site></Sites><ClientPackage FullPackageID="RSP00001" FullPackageVersion="1" FullPackageHash="5EF3A189C48F3469440A83026EC8ECD36EAD6EAF3B5D35663F8201BDE175413C" MinimumClientVersion="5.00.7804.1000" RandomizeMaxDays="7" ProgramEnabled="false" LastModifiedTime="30621757;2748940928" SiteVersionMatch="true" SiteVersion="5.00.7804.1000" EnablePeerCache="true"/></ContentLocationReply>']LOG]!><time="11:39:15.941-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="3064" file="siteinfo.cpp:221">
<![LOG[Failed to get DP locations as the expected version from MP 'WIN-52BO8J9011M.poliforma.nl'. Error 0x87d00215]LOG]!><time="11:39:15.941-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="2" thread="3064" file="ccmsetup.cpp:10926">
<![LOG[MP 'WIN-52BO8J9011M.poliforma.nl' didn't return DP locations for client package with the expected version. Retrying in 30 minutes.]LOG]!><time="11:39:15.941-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="2" thread="3064" file="ccmsetup.cpp:10752">
<![LOG[Next retry in 30 minute(s)...]LOG]!><time="11:39:15.941-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="0" thread="3064" file="ccmsetup.cpp:8498">
```

CCMSetup.exe doesn't seem to stop now.

I reinstalled the management point role from the sccm server, but that didn't work either.

**EDIT:**

When I copied the client installation files from *\Win-52bo8j9011m\sms_rsp\Client*(the sccm server) and tried installing the sccm-client it only installed microsoft silverlight and nothing changed in the configuration manager in the control panel:

[image]

In sccm the client installed is still on no for the windows 7 VM.

A part of the client.msi logfile:

```
[13:38:32] ERROR: Cannot find the IntallUtil.exe C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe. Please install .NET Framework. Cannot find path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
MSI (s) (88:44) [13:38:37:873]: Windows Installer reconfigured the product. Product Name: Configuration Manager Client. Product Version: 5.00.7804.1000. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Reconfiguration success or error status: 0.
```

So I installed .NET Framework and ran the CCMSetup.exe again on the windows 7 VM.

Again the same error in ccmsetup.log:

```
<![LOG[Failed to get assigned site from AD. Error 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="13:58:04.382-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="2" thread="2968" file="ccmsetup.cpp:260">
<![LOG[GetADInstallParams failed with 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="13:58:04.382-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="2968" file="ccmsetup.cpp:300">
```

**EDIT 2:**

I thought I was missing a DLL file in my windows folder called **IComboObject.dll** (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eIgqpQbTcb8).

I [downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJZUc.png) the DLL file and ran a command in my system32 folder:

```
regsvr32 MyComobject.dll
```

I got an error that the file couldn't be found so I searched some more and found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jYaubHmU2yg.). I entered this command in my system32 folder:

```
regsvr32 jscript.dll
```

After that the error was gone from my client.msi and ccmsetup.log file.

I still have no working sccm-client though. I see no client is installed on my windows 7 in my sccm-server.

The errorcode is still 0x80004005, but the message is different now.

Errors in ccmsetup.log:

```
<![LOG[Failed to get assigned site from AD. Error 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="16:54:19.708-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="2" thread="304" file="ccmsetup.cpp:260">
<![LOG[GetADInstallParams failed with 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="16:54:19.708-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="3" thread="304" file="ccmsetup.cpp:300">
<![LOG[Couldn't find an MP source through AD. Error 0x80004005]LOG]!><time="16:54:19.708-120" date="10-17-2017" component="ccmsetup" context="" type="1" thread="304" file="ccmsetup.cpp:4643">
```

Errors I see in client.msi are:

```
[15:52:18] WARNING: Failed to delete setup in progress time-stamp with error 0x80070002
MSI (s) (A8:1C) [15:52:18:142]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=SmsRemoteControlRepairConfig,Description=Repair may require to start Remote Control Service if Remote Control is enalbed.,)
[15:52:18] ERROR: Unable to enumerate files in {3DA228BE-34DA-49f4-A081-66465B077429} (0x80070003)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the fallback status point site system role on my sccm-server:
[image]
[image]

I activated the fallback site on my site:
[image]

In the client push settings I disabled automatic push installation and enabled the option to install in Domain controllers. In the accounts tab I already had my domainadmin. In the installation properties I added my FSP-server (sccm-server with the fallback role).

[image]
[image]
[image]

**FINALY I had my sweet victory:**

Client is installed verification in sccm:
[image]

software center on w7 vm:
[image]

More actions in configuration manager w7:
[image]

[Source of solution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93e9d83b-f1cb-4fb2-b68e-5c6025598d41/sccm-2012-error-failed-to-get-assigned-site-from-ad-error-0x80004005?forum=configmanagersecurity)

**I think the client push settings were the problem, but I must also tell you that I restarted my windows 7 VM.**